# Typescript: implicit no params function type

Tags: typescript, types

I want the qualified type for the functions that are being given as parameters. 
This type I expect either to be a function with no parameters that returns a void function (Action) that does includes parameters or the void function it returns itself.

Here's the code I want to use:

```
interface JsonArray extends Array<string | number | boolean | Date | Json | JsonArray> { }

interface Json {
    [x: string]: string | number | boolean | Date | Json | JsonArray;
}

type Action = (arg1: string, arg2: Json | JsonArray) => void;
type ReturningAction = () => Action;

function required(arg1: string, ...validationFunctions: Array<ReturningAction | Action>) {
    console.log("Test");
}

function oneOf(arg1: string): (arg1: string, arg2: Json | JsonArray) => void {
    return (arg1: string, arg2: Json | JsonArray) => {
        console.log("Testing");
    }
}

function notEmpty(): (arg1: string, arg2: Json | JsonArray) => void {
    return (arg1: string, arg2: Json | JsonArray) => {
        console.log("Empty");
    }
}

required("field", oneOf); // Shouldn't be accepted
required("field", oneOf("test")) // Should be accepted
required("field", notEmpty); // Should be accepted
```

However it seems, TypeScript ignores extra parameters within the function definition than it expects. Can this be solved?

Even when I do the following:

```
function required(arg1: string, ...validationFunctions: Array<(arg1: string, arg2: Json | JsonArray) => void>) {
    console.log("Test");
}

required("field", oneOf); // Shouldn't be accepted
required("field", oneOf("test")) // Should be accepted
required("field", notEmpty); // Shouldn't be accepted
required("field", notEmpty()); // Should be accepted
```

All get accepted for some reason, however only the called functions apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I think you noted, TypeScript [allows](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters) you to pass a function of fewer parameters (e.g., `oneOf()` takes one parameter) to something that expects a function of more parameters (in this case, `validationFunctions[0]` should take two parameters, assuming it's an `Action`).  That's because a function is always free to ignore extra parameters passed in, and causing an error there would lead to annoying errors elsewhere (as the linked section of the TypeScript FAQ explains).

EDIT: The following assumes you're using the `strictNullChecks` compiler option.

One workaround is to declare your `oneOf` and `notEmpty` functions so that they work as normal but fail to be interpreted as `Action` values:

```
function oneOf(arg1: string, nope?: never): (arg1: string, arg2: Json | JsonArray) => void {...}

function notEmpty(nope?: never): (arg1: string, arg2: Json | JsonArray) => void {...}
```

Notice the addition of the `nope` parameter in each case.  Now you should get errors where you expect them.  Since `nope` is an optional parameter, you can leave it out, and since it's of type `never`, you pretty much *have to* leave it out.  So it doesn't really change the way the functions can be used.

---

There are other fixes but they are heavier-weight... for example, you can make `Action` and `ReturningAction` a non-function type which contains the function you want to call.

Hope that helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer! However it does not help the case further because TypeScript does not seem to complain when there is a parameter which expects a function with parameters while you call that function with a function as the parameter which does only have one parameter, an optional nope of type never. Am I doing something wrong or am I correct?

Comment: Haha I can't quite understand that; could you add some code to the question that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Assuming your [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896645) is about this, see my edit: turn on `strictNullChecks`.

Comment: yes, thank you, that would have been smart to mention in the first place haha

Comment: And I am just curious, say I don't want to turn the strictNullChecks compiler option on, what would then be the most appropriate solution? You do mention that other fixes exist but are heavier-weight, and what are the pro's and cons of both solutions? BTW just add it to your answer if you feel like it, if not that's fine ;)