# TypeScript ignores optional parameter of type never

Tags: typescript, types

I don't want a specific function to be passed as a parameter to another function however according to TypeScript it is valid, but is it? and why?

Here's the code example:

```
function spoken(nope?: never): void {
    console.log("He has spoken.");
}

function speak(toSay: string, spoken: (arg1: string) => void): void {
    console.log("He says: " + toSay);
    spoken("He has spoken.");
}

speak("Hello world.", spoken);
```

Because basically, TypeScript says type string is assignable to type never, because if nope were of lets say type number, TypeScript would complain because type string isn't compatible to type number.

Comment: What is the point here exactly? If you don't want the `spoken` function to receive an argument then just don't declare one?

Comment: When you say "according to TypeScript it is valid", what do you mean?  You should turn on the `strictNullChecks` compiler option; you will see the error you are expecting.  Turning off `strictNullChecks` is not a great idea, especially for new code (having it `false` temporarily while migrating from pure JS is reasonable).

Comment: BTW this is apparently related to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45469099/2887218) to @WilcoBakker's previous question

Comment: @jcalz yes, as a matter of fact it is a direct follow up question based on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short Answer

> ...according to TypeScript it is valid, but is it? and why?

Yes, it is valid, because TypeScript says that type `never` is assignable to type `string`. Here is [some code in typescript/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20arg1%3A%20string%20%3D%20(null%20as%20never)%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0Alet%20arg2%3A%20never%20%3D%20(null%20as%20string)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fails%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20The%20situation%20with%20spoken%20is%20similar%0D%0Afunction%20spoken(nope%3F%3A%20never)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22He%20has%20spoken.%22)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20spokenParam%3A%20(arg1%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20void%3B%0D%0AspokenParam%20%3D%20spoken%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A) to demonstrate.

### Details on `never`

The [Basic Types documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html) says:

> The never type is a subtype of, and assignable to, every type; however, no type is a subtype of, or assignable to, never (except never itself).

That means we can assign `never` to `string` but cannot assign `string` to `never`.

```
let arg1: string = (null as never); // works
let arg2: never = (null as string); // fails
```

### Details on Your Situation

Your `speak` function has a parameter named `spoken`, which is a function that has an `arg1` parameter of type `string`. Here is the `spoken` parameter on its own.

```
let spokenParam: (arg1: string) => void;
```

Since `arg1` is a `string` and `string` is a super-type of `never`, the following assignment is valid.

```
function spoken(nope?: never): void {
    console.log("He has spoken.");
}

spokenParam = spoken;
```